# AppleScript for scripting Outlook does not work on all machines

Tags: applescript

We use the following AppleScript for setting Microsoft Outlook signatures on client Macs.  I boiled it down to a minimum to reproduce the error.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    make new signature with properties {name:"Test", content:"Hello", plain text content:"", include in random:false}
end tell
```

The problem is that it is working fine on most machines but on a few Macs it fails with the error message

> Expected ":" but found id.

If we run the script in the script editor on the problem machines, the words "text content" are highlighted in the editor as being the cause of the error.

All Macs run the same version of Outlook.

Does anybody know why the script works on some machines but not on others?

Comment: Maybe try removing `plain text content:""` altogether, as it doesn't appear to have any data.

Comment: @l'L'l: Thanks, but `plain text content` is left empty for this simple example only.

Comment: I seem to encounter the same error as well; I'm curious what the differentiating factor might be. What data would normally be within `plain text content`? If I take it out then I get an error with `include in random:false` - `Expected “:” but found “in”.`

Comment: @l'L'l: Interesting.  Does it work for you if you take out both `plain text content` and `include in random`?

Comment: Yes, it does work after I remove both of those items. If Outlook has the variable `plain text content` AppleScript should see it in it's dictionary, so odd why it's finding it on some machines and not the others.

Comment: @l'L'l: Yes, it's odd and also quite annoying.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try to wrap your code inside an `using terms from application "Microsoft Outlook"`-Block? Maybe it forces Applescript to interprete your code correctly...

Comment: You sure all machines are on the same version of Outlook? Sounds like they don't all have the same terminology available. AppleScript can't compile app-defined keywords if it doesn't have the right terminology. Compare the dictionaries from good and bad Outlook apps in Script Editor to see if they've both define a `plain text content` property. (Easiest is just to open the app's dictionary in SE, then type the phrase in the searchbox at top-right of the dictionary viewer window.)